# problem in displaying list in vf page

Tags: visualforce

Page :

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >

                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
        <APEX:PAGEBlock > 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" var="c"></apex:pageBlockTable>
        </APEX:PAGEBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex :

```
public class wrapperClassController {
    public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

    public List<cContact> getContacts() {
        if(contactList == null) {
            contactList = new List<cContact>();
            for(Account c: [select Id, Name from Account limit 10]) {
                contactList.add(new cContact(c));
            }
        }
        return contactList;
    }

    public PageReference processSelected() {
        List<Account> selectedContacts = new List<Account>();
        for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
            if(cCon.selected == true) {
                selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
            }
        }

        System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
        for(Account con: selectedContacts) {
            system.debug(con);
        }
        contactList=null; 
        return null;
    }

    public class cContact {
        public Account con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public cContact(Account c) {
            con = c;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

i want to access con in vf page but giving error as follows,Error

> Error: Unknown property 'wrapperClassController.con'   Quick Fix  Create
>   Apex property 'sahi__wrapperClassController.con' Quick Fix    Create Apex
>   method 'sahi__wrapperClassController.getCon'

please help how to fix it,urgent requirement.

Comment: you are trying to access con in page `value="{!con}"` where is it ?

Comment: see in controller

Comment: con is inside wrapper class. you can't access directly in vf page

Comment: i want to display records of con.

Comment: what to do to display the records of con.kindly help,,needed

Comment: you are displaying already i.e. `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">` .. would you like to add more info in your question what you are trying to do..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40537/discussion-between-ratan-and-sahisfdc).

Comment: top pageblock table is to display first 10 accounts in vf page,if i select any of the 10 ten records and click on Process Selected,then it has to show the selected records in another pageblock table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your code. Try this code

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" 
                                                                        rerender="test" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock id="test">
            Total No of Selected Records :
            <apex:outputText value="{!value }" />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Email}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.Phone}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class wrapperClassController {
    public List < cContact > contactList {get;set;}
    public List < Contact > selectedContacts {get;set;}
    public Integer value {get;set;}
    public List < cContact > getContacts() {
        if (contactList == null) {
            contactList = new List < cContact > ();
            for (Contact c: [select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact limit 10]) {
                contactList.add(new cContact(c));
            }
        }
        return contactList;
    }
    public PageReference processSelected() {
        selectedContacts = new List < Contact > ();
        for (cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
            if (cCon.selected == true) {
                selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
            }
        }
        value = selectedContacts.size();
        System.debug('printingtcontc' + selectedContacts.size());
        return null;
    }
    public List < Contact > getSelectedContacts() {
        System.debug('printingtcontc inside get' + selectedContacts.size());
        if (selectedContacts.size() > 0) return selectedContacts;
            else return null;
        }
        public class cContact {
            public Contact con {get;set;}
            public Boolean selected {get;set;}
            public cContact(Contact c) {
                con = c;
                selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

You need a second list to store selected contact and display them on VF page.

Comment: thanq Tushar Sharma,working finwe for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update the code. Please check the below.

Controller

```
public class wrapperClassController {
    public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}
    public  List<Account> selectedContacts {get; set;}

    public List<cContact> getContacts() {
        if(contactList == null) {
            contactList = new List<cContact>();
            for(Account c: [select Id, Name from Account limit 10]) {
                contactList.add(new cContact(c));
            }
        }
        return contactList;
    }
    public PageReference processSelected() {

        selectedContacts = new List<Account>();

        for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
            if(cCon.selected == true) {
                selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
            }
        }

        System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
        for(Account con: selectedContacts) {
            system.debug(con);
        }
        contactList=null; 
        return null;
    }
    public class cContact {

        public Account con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public cContact(Account c) {
            con = c;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
    <apex:form id="myform">
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="myform"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedContacts}" var="c">
                <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Screen

[image]